# How to move lifetime of "this" into another object in C++?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

I want to simulate Rust `bar(self, ...)` functions in C++, so I write something like this:

```
class Foo;

class Bar {
public:
    explicit Bar(unique_ptr<Foo> foo);
private:
    unique_ptr<Foo> _foo;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Bar bar() {
        return Bar(unique_ptr<Foo>(this));
    }
};

Bar::Bar(unique_ptr<Foo> foo) : _foo(move(foo)) {}

TEST_CASE("Convert a Foo object into a Bar object") {
    Bar b = Foo().bar();
}
```

This code segment would throw a segment fault. Because `Foo()` and `b` both think they own `Foo`'s instance and it will be cleaned twice. How to fix it?

---

I will describe what I want to do. In the following code:

```
auto foo = unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
Bar b = some_func(move(foo));
```

After the calling to `some_func`, the lifetime of `foo` is "transferred" to `some_func`, and we could not use `foo` any more. A convertor function should be designed this way, if `b` inherits `foo`'s resources. In my situation, I would like `some_func` becomes an instance method of `foo`. And that's it.

Comment: It depends of what you really want. Maybe `return Bar(std::make_unique<Foo>(*this))` ?

Comment: For those of us who don't know Rust, can you explain the semantics of what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Angew you are right, and I have done the editing

Comment: @Jarod42 that's a good idea, but `Foo`'s instance is something could not be copied, because it contains unique resources.

Comment: @Cowsay If `Foo` *contains unique resources*, then it sounds like it might refer to them indirectly (since value types tend not to be unique). As such, are you sure it makes sense to force dynamic allocation through using a unique pointer? Might it make sense to store a `Foo` value instance instead like you would do with a vector or a string? Also, why would you want this to be a member function of `Foo`? Why not simply use a converting constructor: `Bar::Bar(Foo&&)`? Then you could simply write `Bar b = Foo()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want this line from the test case to be valid:

```
Bar b = Foo().bar();
```

And you want its effect to be that `b` gets a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to play with.

If that's the case, you will have to implement `bar` to create a new instace of `Foo`, because `Foo()` is a temporary whose lifetime cannot become dynamic in the way you'd want to. You've mentioned in comments that `Foo` cannot be copied, but it can presumably be moved:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Bar bar() && {
        return Bar(std::make_unique<Foo>(std::move(*this)));
    }
};
```

Note that I made `bar` rvalue-qualified, so that it cannot be called on lvalues (because it moved from `*this`). To call it on an lvalue, you'd have to `move` from it:

```
Foo().bar();  // rvalue calls are fine
Foo f;
std::move(f).bar();  // lvalue must be moved
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing what std::move is doing, and assuming that it transfers object ownership.
It does not.

Everything that std::move does is convert to an rvalue reference, so that an appropriate function that takes an rvalue reference parameter can be called.

To my knowledge, you can't extend the lifetime of an object from within the object itself.
In the example you provided, you're creating a temporary object of class Foo, which will be destroyed as soon as bar() returns.

One thing you can do is declare your some_func function to take an rvalue reference, like this:

```
Bar some_func(std::unique_ptr<Foo>&& someFoo)
{ 
   Bar someBar(std::move(someFoo));
   return someBar;
}

int main() {
   auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
   //do stuff with foo
   Bar b = some_func(std::move(foo));
   //foo is now invalid, and can't be used;
   //b has ownership of foo
   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this answers your questions and does what you would expect it to. The take-away is that instead of creating a temporary, you're creating an object with make_unique, and you're moving around the unique pointer to whichever object you want to own your instance.